# Is there any specific name for airport kind shops?

Tags: vocabulary

Is there an specific name for the shops structures like the ones on shopping malls or in the airports. I mean all of them share this specific characteristics: a very open space with almost no walls and burried inside a larger facility that almost always cover them in shadows and therefore has to be lit artificially.

I mean right now airport shops become more and more homogeneous. I was wondering and almost entirely sure that they must have a name.

Comment: Perhaps [**open-plan**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/open-plan).

Comment: @WeatherVane It suits well. Thanks everyone!

Comment: How about *skymall*?  I think this actually exists somewhere.

Comment: @GlobalCharm, I think Sky Mall is a catalog you can order from while on an airplane. So not a physical shop at all.

Comment: @The Photon I think you’re right. Just something I browse through, but never actually buy anything. Still, there’s Hudson News. Maybe a single physical store could stand for the whole thing. Vino Volo maybe. And there are some kiosks that seem to be everywhere.